# 403 Forbidden when accessing WebSocket using Expo Go

Tags: python, react-native

I have created a websocket in FastAPI in accordance with the documentation, i.e.

```
@app.websocket("/stream_movement/push_ups/")
async def websocket_stream_movement_push_ups(websocket: WebSocket):
    print("---WEB SOCKET---")
    with open("./push-ups.txt", mode="w") as file:
        headers_str = "\n".join([f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in websocket.headers.items()])
        file.write(headers_str)

    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        try:
            data = await websocket.receive_json()
            _ = data["valueA"] + data["valueB"]

            await websocket.send_json({"detail": "success", "exercise": "push-ups"})

        except WebSocketDisconnect:
            break
```

This code works locally, i.e. when I run any script which needs to connect with this socket I am able to receive and send some data.

Unfortunately when I try to run my mobile application using Expo Go a 403 Forbidden error raises. Moreover the text is not printed and the headers are not saved into a file. It seems that this function is not even called.

I have double-checked my IP address and the url to which I need to connect, both are connect. Do you have any ideas how to solve my problem?